Apply custom ESLint rules for execution in a specific directory
I wrote some custom rules for my company:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-t1-group?activeTab=readme
All rules work except that everything in my code is checked, although I would like only for a specific page (in folder pages).
For example, for the rule:
https://github.com/Emil768/t1-group-eslint/blob/main/lib/rules/moment-constants-required.js
I want to make the conditions that apply the rules only if this is a page?

I tried checking through where in filename I pass context.getFilename()
function getPageName(filename) {
  return path.basename(path.dirname(filename));
}

Where in the end I get the name of one page utils/store, etc. But I still write the conditions that getPageName(context.getFilename()) ==="pages" it doesn’t work.
Now it’s clear that the page rule applies not only to pages, how to solve the problem?



Does this answer your question? Make ESLint apply rules to only certain file name patterns

Not really, I don't think I need to touch the commands in package.json, for certain rules I only need specific pages

You want to apply specific rules to a specific path. This is the solution.

managed to configure it this way
overrides: [   {    files: ['src/pages/**/*.js'],    rules: {     't1-group/moment-constants-required': 'error',    },   },  ],

Glad it helped, please accept the duplicate.
